# 403 Forbidden issue for uploaded file

Tags: file-upload, smarty

My site is hosted in Parallels panel. When i upload the image file from front end. Its uploading the file . But the file permission is changed to 600. But my folder is in 755.

Please help

Answer (score 0):

Hi I had fixed the issue.

Just changed chmod($savePath.$saveFilename,0600);

to chmod($savePath.$saveFilename,0644);